# How do I conditionally include a tag in the middle of some HTML in React

Tags: javascript, syntax, reactjs

I have an `Avatar` React component and there's an option to make it link to a profile or not. You may not want it to link to a profile if, say, your on the users profile and instead you want to do a custom `clickHandler`. Is there a nicer way other than just doing an if/else with basically identical HTML in each if and else other than a link? Below is some pseudo rendering code just to show an example of what I mean:

```js
 <div className={"Avatar Avatar--" + this.props.size} onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>
    {if (this.props.link) { 
      <Link to="profile" params={{userId:this.props.user.id}}>
     }
    }

      <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} />

    {if (this.props.link) {
      </Link> 
     }
    }
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<div className={"Avatar Avatar--" + this.props.size} onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>
{ this.props.link ?
  <Link to="profile" params={{userId:this.props.user.id}}>
    <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} />
  </Link>
  : <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} /> }
```

You can try to eliminate double definition of img by defining it earlier:

```
var img = <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} />;
```

and embed it using:

```
{img}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a function that either returns the image or the image wrapped in the link and then add it to the div.

```
var createAvatar = function() {
  if (this.props.link) {
    return <Link to="profile" params={{userId:this.props.user.id}}>
      <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} />
    </Link>;
  } else {
    return <img className="__avatarimage" src={this.props.user.avatar} />;
  }
};

var avatar = createAvatar();
return <div className={"Avatar Avatar--" + this.props.size} onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>
  {avatar}
</div>;
```